# Command not working in crontab

Tags: shell-script, cron

I have small check if today is first Monday of month which is like this:

```
['$(date "+%u")' = "1"] && echo 'trąba'
```

but I get the error when crontab is sending me an email that something went wrong

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I tried changing *'$(date "+%u")'* to "$(date '+%u')" but didn't help.
The title of the email is ["$(date '+ so I think it has a problem with 1st quote marks
but this code works just fine when executed inside the terminal.
Maybe someone have better "check" to check for the 1st Monday of month

OS: CeontOS 7

contab -l

```
* * * * * [ "$(date +%u)" -eq 1 ] && echo trąba
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed POSIX code follows:

```sh
[ "$(date +%u)" -eq 1 ] && echo trąba
```

Errors / warnings / infos were:

- missing spaces in `[` .. `]` block
- apostrophes instead of double quotes
- equal sign instead of POSIX `-eq` in test `[` .. `]`
- you do not have to quote anything after `echo`
- you do not have to quote numbers
- you do not have to quote that `date` code

---

### Cron

```
*/1 * * * * [ "$(/usr/bin/date +\%u)" -eq 1 ] && /usr/bin/echo trąba >> ~/cron-test
```

- In order to test this, you may try the above code
- You may have your `date` and `echo` binaries elsewhere on your system, to determine where they are, use `which date` etc.
- After modifying your Cron, you can simply use this and sit tight

  ```
  tail -f ~/cron-test
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In the command part of a crontab entry, `%` is translated to a line break before the command is executed, unless it's escaped. So you need to escape the one in the date format string.

Other problems: you need spaces between the `[ ]` and the things inside them, and `$( )` won't expand inside single-quotes. Here's the fixed version:

```
[ "$(date "+\%u")" = "1" ] && echo 'trąba'
```

Comment: with my knowledge crontab with 0 2 1-7 * 1 will run on everyday AND monday

Comment: @Viszman You're right; I checked the `man` page, and it says "Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day of month, and day of week.  If both fields  are  restricted  (i.e., don't  start with *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time." So I'll remove that part of my answer.